# Code : importing modified cells and adding them in the bottom of the column

Tags: vba, excel

**Original issue:**

I want to import a column in an other sheet and update it by adding the modified cells at the bottom.
I tried the code below but it gives an error in the third line can someone help me?

Fixed by defining lrow

```
lRow = Worksheets("Analyse de risque").Range("C6").End(xlDown).Row
```

**New issue:**

It just adds the same column many times at the bottom, i don't understand why?

```
Public Sub Refreshing()

    Dim aCell As Range

    If Worksheets("Analyse").Range("C6:C" & lRow).Cells.Count > 1 Then

        For Each aCell In Worksheets("Analyse").Range("C6:C" & lRow).Cells

            With aCell

                Dim wsI As Worksheet
                Dim lRowWsI As Long, lRowWsO As Long

                '~~> Find the last row where the data needs to go
                lRowWsO = Worksheets("PTR").Range("B" & Worksheets("PTR").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

                '~~> Set Input Sheet
                Set wsI = Worksheets("Analyse")

                With wsI

                    '~~> Find Last Row to get the range you want to copy
                    lRowWsI = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

                    '~~> Do the final Copy
                    .Range("C6:C" & lRowWsI).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("PTR").Range("B" & lRowWsO)

               End With

           End With

       Next

       Application.CutCopyMode = False

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: of course you find error in the third line,  lRow is not defined

Comment: Thank u ..I added 
lRow = Worksheets("Analyse de risque").Range("C6").End(xlDown).Row
But it just add the same column many times at the buttom ...i don't understand why ..

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to loop through the cells in the Analyse sheet. You just need to do the copy and paste one time.

Get rid of:

```
        For Each aCell In Worksheets("Analyse").Range("C6:C" & lRow).Cells

            With aCell
```

and the `End With` and the `Next` that match the lines you got rid of.